# Ember app that consumes json getting error "XMLHttpRequest cannot load"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ember.js

I have a rails app on heroku that is serving up data via an API. This data looks like...

```
[{"created_at":"2014-02-20T17:22:02Z","id":1,"name":"Joe Rogan","twitter":"@joerogan","updated_at":"2014-02-20T17:22:02Z"},{"created_at":"2014-02-20T17:22:11Z","id":2,"name":"Kristen Schaa","twitter":"@kchalithis","updated_at":"2014-02-20T17:22:11Z"},{"created_at":"2014-02-20T17:29:10Z","id":3,"name":"Casey Grim","twitter":"@aCoupleofN3rds","updated_at":"2014-02-20T17:29:16Z"}]
```

I pulled down the [Ember Start Kit](https://github.com/emberjs/starter-kit) and have modified it to pull data from my API with code like this...

## js/app.js

```
App.Person.adapter = Ember.RESTAdapter.create();
App.Person.url = "http://myapp.herokuapp.com/api/v1/shots?api_key=12d2d06fb2f6a786ac75b32625cf83a1";
App.Person.collectionKey = "people";
```

## index.html

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
    <ul>
    {{#each item in model}}
      <li>{{item.name}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </script>
```

I thought I could start chrome like this...

```
google-chrome --disable-web-security
```

And get it working just for testing, but that does not work.

Also, Sounds like I need to use jsonp rather than json? But not sure how to implement in ember (or really anywhere else). Any help appreciated. Thanx!

## Update

Added :cors_set_access_control_headers before filter in my rails app. looks like...

```
module Api
  module V1
    class ShotsController < ApplicationController
      before_filter :cors_set_access_control_headers
...
def cors_set_access_control_headers
        headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
        headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, PUT, DELETE, GET, OPTIONS'
        headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = '*'
        headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
      end
```

...but still getting error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot /api/v1/shots?api_key=d26da3938adc5f3c8604256194c18501.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

...if I issue a curl to look at headers I'm seeing Access Controll set to *...

```
me@me-E6530:~$ curl -v http://myapp.herokuapp.com/api/v1/shots?api_key=12d2d06fb2f6a786ac75b32625cf83a1
* About to connect() to myapp.herokuapp.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 54.243.169.60... connected
> GET /api/v1/shots?api_key=12d2d06fb2f6a786ac75b32625cf83a1 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
> Host: myapp.herokuapp.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, PUT, DELETE, GET, OPTIONS
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Request-Method: *
```

Answer (score 0):

Ember expects response in the following format:

```
{
  people: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "John Doe"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Jane Doe"
    }
  ]
}
```

Also you may need to [enable CORS](http://enable-cors.org/) if they are on different domains.

Comment: Updated my question to address CORS issue, but still getting the same error.

Comment: Make sure it works by testing it with curl or something and don't forget to return collection array with 'people' key.

Comment: You can also try [ActiveModelSerializer gem](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers), it works great with ember.